# Is there way to inherit a custom control from other than UserControl in Visual Basic 6?

Tags: vb6

I am developing a custom VB6 control - actually a PictureBox like control with scrollbars. As far as I understand all the controls in VB6 are derived from the UserControl class by default. I would like my control to provide the PictureBox interface with Line, PSet, Circle methods. How can I inherit from the PictureBox class or provide the PictureBox control's interface?

Comment: I don't use VB6 :-) However, consider using Composition instead of Inheritance.

Comment: For a "picture box with scrollbars", have a look at [Adding Scrollbars To Forms, PictureBoxes, and UserControls](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/vb/code/libraries/subclassing/Adding_Scroll_Bars_To_Forms__PictureBoxes_and_UserControls/article.asp), which may save a bit of work. Happy coding.

Comment: That's how I am trying to solve this. However, the problem is PSet method name is reserved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use UserControl as the base.
But VB6 IDE provides a wizard for this situation.

#### Poor man's inheritance:

- Create an empty user control.
- Add a picturebox on it. Give it a proper name right away.
- Go to `Add-Ins -> Add-in Manager...`.
- Activate `VB 6 ActiveX Ctrl Interface Wizard` and close the manager.
- `Add-Ins -> ActiveX Control Interface Wizard...`.
- `Next >`.
- Select properties you want your control to have. `Next >`.
- `Next >`.
- Now you have your list of properties on the left and a list of child controls on the right. Click a property, then select `PictureBoxName` from the dropdown to map that property to a property of the picturebox. By default it's the property with the same name, but can be changed to anything.
  Repeat that for each property. You will hate it. `Next >`.
- Make changes to visibility/data types settings if you wish.
- Click Finish.

Comment: +1. This is the official way to "inherit" your user control from another control. You **will** hate it. You will hate it even more if you ever have to upgrade your code to VB.Net, because the VB.Net upgrade wizard won't upgrade usercontrols. I'm not sure how you're going to add scrollbars to your "inherited" picturebox. If it was me, I might look into writing a .Net control and exposing it to VB6 through COM interop.